# How do I run a PHP if statement if the user is not on a certain page?

Tags: php

How do I run a PHP if statement if the user is not on a certain page?

For example, if the user was on hello.php, the `if` statement wouldn't run, but if they were on other pages, it would.

Comment: One possible solution would be to create a separate PHP file for the `IF` statement and only include it on pages you need it.

Comment: I considered that, however that gets complicated when you have a `header.php` and all that. Is something like my question not possible in a few simple lines of code?

Comment: If you are looking to put that code into your `header.php` using a `$_SESSION` variable or the whole `$_GET` or `$_POST` system could work along with an `if` statement as well. There are many options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])!="hello.php") {
    if(YOUR_CONDITION) {
        //YOUR STATEMENTS GOES HERE
    }
}
```

`basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` will return you the current page, by utilizing this you can notice the traverse and make conditions on it.

Comment: Nice. Learned something as well! Thanks for that.